# Search a specific file for a string of text

Tags: php

Long time reader, first time poster.

I'm creating a form that would grab certain values from a specific url and would grab that value and using $_GET to post specific information/values.

Lets call this url examplecode.com/someindex.html, in this I'd see: `<td class="ColumnMargin"><label for="quote_Customer_Name">Contact:</label></td><td class="QuoteNameText"><input class="TabOnEnter widenFieldsWidth" id="quote_Customer_Name" name="quote_Customer_Name" tabindex="110" type="text" value="JOHN DOE" /></td>`

I've been searching for days and I've tried numerous things, all I'm trying to do is open this URL, inspect it, find either id "quote_Customer_Name" or name "quote_Customer_Name" and grab the value from this and then echo it on the page(it being JOHN DOE) somewhere.

I'm a very beginner in PHP code, I've done simple things in the past, this is out of my comfort zone but I honestly don't know where to look. I'm hoping someone could help me because I don't know where to even begin.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` to parse HTML.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this. I will give you a simple example with url "[Salam Tresno](https://laguf1.mobi/download-lagu-shinta-arsinta-ft-dj-santuy-salam-tresno-mp3/WwUJmaSpX3s.html)".
We will take its h1 tag and display it.

```js
<?php

$url = 'url ....';
// fetch html
$html = file_get_contents($url);

// find and match h1 tag
preg_match('#<h1[^><]*>.+?</h1>#', $html, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```